# Devise and rvm having issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rvm

I am trying to run:

```
rails generate devise User
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `const_get': uninitialized constant User (NameError)
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `block in constantize'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `each'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `inject'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `constantize'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:297:in `get'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_used_route'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:331:in `new'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:331:in `add_mapping'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:221:in `block in devise_for'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:220:in `each'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:220:in `devise_for'
    from /home/zach/HandCoOp/project/HandCo-op/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `eval_block'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:315:in `draw'
    from /home/zach/HandCoOp/project/HandCo-op/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:71:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
    from /home/zach/HandCoOp/project/HandCo-op/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:147:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:133:in `generate_or_destroy'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `generate'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I am not quite sure exactly what is going wrong here and I will keep looking into the issue.  Thanks anyone who knows what my problem here is.  I am following the guide here : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise but am defiantly having issues.

Comment: 1. make sure to have added `gem 'devise'` to `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`).
2. Only after you have done it you can proceed with `rails generate devise:install`. what is the output of rake db:migrate now?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't have enough karma to comment, so I'll do the best I can to provide a solution here.

Have you made sure to run 'rails generate devise:install' before attempting to generate the devise model? Also make sure that you ran 'bundle install' before you attempt either of installing Devise or generating a model.

Answer (score 0):

hope u followed these steps:-

1. Add `gem 'devise'` to gemfile
2. `Run the bundle` command to install it.
3. After you install Devise and add it to your Gemfile, you need to run the generator:

   ```
                 rails generate devise:install
   ```

The generator will install an initializer which describes ALL Devise's configuration options and you MUST take a look at it.
 4. When you are done, you are ready to add Devise to any of your models using the generator:

```
rails generate devise MODEL
```

Comment: I get the same error after bundle completes and I run the install command. devise is inside my gemfile.